# How to keep ElasticSearch up-to-date with SQLServer without code?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm dealing with a table in SQLServer that I need indexed in ElasticSearch in near realtime.  Records are added/updated/deleted in this table from various points (legacy code, stored procedures, etc.) so instrumenting the code to find all areas that interact with this table is not feasible.  What technique and/or tool would allow for this?

Note:  Table in SQLServer contains roughly 10 columns and could include up to a million rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it with minimal code, then you can set it up with Logstash jdbc plugin(now that river concept is no longer supported in Elasticsearch). In the table have a last updated timestamp column. You can configure you polling query to be based on it so that it can pickup changes since last run. Make sure to have index defined on this timestamp column. Since this is will be a polling process, just dont go over board and set very low polling interval as that might end up putting unnecessary work load on the SQL DB server.

If you ready to do it the right way and ready to spend time coding, then probably you should consider SQL Server service broker option. You can have trigger on the table to write a message and an external polling/trigger process on the queue to pickup the message/change and push it to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When you said to keep the polling interval low, you were only concerned about SQLServer and not ElasticSearch?

Comment: Right. I was talking about load on SQL Server DB. With some testing, you should be able to determine, what frequency is acceptable without unncessarily increasing load on SQL Server.

Comment: I would think using polling to create service broker would be better than using triggers. Thoughts, @askids?

Comment: It all depends on the data volume and the frequency of polling. If you need near real time update, then polling is not the right solution. However, if you are okay with some lag and your tables are structured to support polling, then you may be okay to use polling. Also for using service broker, you need not necessarily use trigger. That is just a way to externalize it. Else you can send message to broker directly from SP also. Trigger in itself can bring in additional overheads. May not be bad in all cases. But may not recommendable in all cases as well. There is no 1 size fits all answer:)